# Persisting JSF2 Composite Component value

Tags: jboss, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a datatable which loops through a List and has a value column which renders as such:

```
<h:dataTable var="assessmentFieldValue" value="#{assessmentBean.assessmentFieldValues}">
    ...
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{assessmentFieldValue.field.type eq 'TEXT'}">
        <h:inputText value="#{assessmentFieldValue.value}" />
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{assessmentFieldValue.field.type eq 'SLIDER'}">
        <component:slider value="#{assessmentFieldValue.value}" />
    </ui:fragment>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

So sometimes I get a standard inputText, sometimes I get my composite slider component:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        function updateValue(value) {
            $('##{cc.id} span').each(function() {
                $(this).text(value);
            });
        }
    </script>

    <div id="#{cc.id}">
        <input id="sliderComponent" type="range" min="1" max="10"
                value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                style="float: left"
                onchange="javascript:updateValue(this.value);" />

        <h:outputText id="fieldValue" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                style="min-width: 20px; display: block; float: left" />
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

This all renders as I would like it too (deployed on JBoss-AS7), but when I hit the save button associated with the datatable the assessmentBean.assessmentFieldValue List doesn't reflect any value changes on the slider component yet it *does* for the standard inputText.

Can anyone suggest why changes to the slider aren't making it back to the backing bean? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you used a plain HTML `<input>` element instead of a fullworthy JSF input component like `<h:inputText>`. This way the value is in no way bound to the JSF context. It's only treated as plain vanilla template output value, not as input value. A composite component isn't going to solve this. You **really** need to create a fullworthy `UIComponent` for this (or to look for a 3rd party component library which has already done the nasty job for you, such as PrimeFaces with its [`<p:slider>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/slider.jsf)).

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-component)